# Ifstream - Reset EOF bit

Tags: c++, ifstream, eof

I'm working with `ifstream`. I read until the `EOF` bit is set (I need it this way).

Why then doesn't this work?

```
// IN is ifstream file. CH is char.

if (IN.eof()) {
    IN.seekg(ios::beg);
    IN.clear();

    if (read((char*)&CH, sizeof(CH)))
        cout << "Success.";
    else
        cout << "Not S.";    
}
```

The `read` function is never successful. I tried using `IN.setstate(ifstream::goodbit)` instead of `IN.clear()`. But it still fails, am I right?

Comment: That code is not valid. You'd have to call `read` on the actual `istream` object.

Comment: BTW: generally speaking ALLCAPS is used for MACROS and DEFINEs.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Change your code like this:

```
IN.clear();
IN.seekg(0, ios::beg);
```